# How would I code a hangman game with multiple outcomes possible?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to code a hangman game that prints different words when the player gets the word with a certain amount of lives left, but I can't figure out how to do that. I have everything else put in place expect this concept. I have tried elif statements, but don't know what else to try except for this:

```
lives_remaining = 14
guessed_letters = ''

def play():
    word = pick_a_word()
    while True:
        guess = get_guess(word)
        if first_try(guess, word):
            print('Excellent!')
            break
        elif second_try(guess, word):
            print('Great!')
            break
        elif third_try(guess, word):
            print('Ok!')
            break
        elif fourth_try(guess, word):
            print('Close one!')
            break
        elif lives_remaining == 0:
            print('Nope!')
            print('The word was: ' + (word))
            break

def first_try(guess, word):
    if lives_remaining > 12:

def second_try(guess, word):
    if lives_remaining > 8:

def third_try(guess, word):
    if lives_remaining > 4:

def fourth_try(guess, word):
    if lives_remaining > 0:

def pick_a_word():
    return random.choice(words)

def get_guess(word):
    print_word_with_blanks(word)
    print('Lives Remaining: ' + str(lives_remaining))
    guess = raw_input(' Guess a letter or whole word?')
    return guess

def print_word_with_blanks(word):
    display_word = ''
    for letter in word:
        if guessed_letters.find(letter) > -1:
            # letter found
            display_word = display_word + letter
        else:
            # letter not found
            display_word = display_word + '-'
    print(display_word)

def process_guess(guess, word):
    if len(guess) > 1:
        return whole_word_guess(guess, word)
    else:
        return single_letter_guess(guess, word)


def whole_word_guess(guess, word):
    global lives_remaining
    if guess == word:
        return True
    else:
        lives_remaining = lives_remaining - 1
        return False

def single_letter_guess(guess, word):
    global guessed_letters
    global lives_remaining
    if word.find(guess) == -1:
        # letter guess was incorrect
        lives_remaining = lives_remaining - 1
    guessed_letters = guessed_letters + guess
    if all_letters_guessed(word):
        return True
    return False

def all_letters_guessed(word):
    for letter in word:
        if guessed_letters.find(letter) == -1:
            return False
    return True

play()
```

I just don't know how I could possibly make those functions work.
 Any input would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :) What have you tried so far to make it work? What part of the code isn't working quite right? Please see [ask] about tips on how to properly ask questions. SO is not a programming service, we are a community for everyone to learn together. As such, askers should provide details as to what they have already tried and what they are specifically struggling with, but asking for someone to code for you isn't appropriate.

Comment: For sure! I'll edit my post :)

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: It is looking better, when you post your code you don't need to show the entire program it can just be enough to give a background as to what you are doing and the specific code that you're struggling with. Though that's more of an opinion as to how much to show that way someone looking to help can more easily see where the error is or where help is needed.

Answer (score 0):

```
if numberOfLives == 1:
    print 'response1'
elif numberOfLives == 2:
    print 'response2'
elif ...
```

You could also [use a dictionary](https://www.pydanny.com/why-doesnt-python-have-switch-case.html).